# ListView with different cell types?

Tags: android, listview, cell

Until now I used to populate my `ListView` this way, using `SimpleAdapter`:

```
// Example of a list with cells containing some text and an image
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), list, R.layout.my_cell, 
              new String[] {"img", "title"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.title});

list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

This solution works pretty well but with it I can only use one kind of cell, here `my_cell`.

Any idea to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override some adapter methods, most importantly: `getViewTypeCount()`, `getItemViewType()`, and `getView()`.

`getViewTypeCount()` returns the number of different view types in your adapter.
`getItemViewType()` returns the view type for a specific position within the adapter.
`getView()` will have to create a view of the correct type if `convertView` is `null`.
If convertView is not `null`, it will be of the correct type based on the information previously returned by `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.

P.S.  @Rob All my examples are pretty big so I'll try to explain it briefly:
Suppose you have only 2 view types.

- `getViewTypeCount()` should return 2
- `getItemViewType()` should return 0 or 1, depending on the `position` parameter.  This method will be called before `getView()`
- `getView()` will be called with the same `position` parameter that was used to call `getItemViewType()`.  Using the same `position`-based algorithm as you used in `getItemViewType()` determine which view type should be returned (you can even re-use `getItemViewType()` here).  Then check if `convertView` for null.

  - If it is null, create a new view of the correct type and bind the values.
  - If it is not null, just re-use it and bind the values. Android passes the correct view type when it re-uses the view.

Comment: This is the correct answer. With multiple view types you must, at the very least, override those three methods.

Comment: You are welcome Rob.  And thanks for up voting Rob & @Bobbake4 :)

Comment: But if it's possible, I would like to ask you to add just a little example about this situation... I still have some problems to understand this.

Comment: Rob I added more explanation to the answer, hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Now that's great I succeeded to do what I want. Thanks again.